# Should we delete the essay tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently 36 questions **[tagged, "essay"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/essay)**. Nearly two thirds of them are closed or on hold. Most of the questions tagged with [essay](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/essay) are due to OP needing to write an essay, rather than being about essays. Let's consider deleting this tag.

Is there any way that future use of the tag can be blocked, so that it doesn't reappear in new questions?

Comment: I completely agree. Not much can be done here with a question about essays in the first place.

Comment: Yes. The tag is useless.

Comment: So, do we have a consensus? I don't know if deleting a flag can be done globally, as a moderator task, or if I should just get busy removing it, question by question.

Comment: Delete all the tags. They serve no purpose and are hopelessly disorganized.

Comment: @JohnLawler Delete **ALL** the tags?  I wouldn't mind doing that, but will start with [tag:essay].

Comment: I disagree with @JohnLawler's comment about the tags. They do serve a purpose, and that is allowing one to narrow down a search. They're also useful for people who specialise in a particular topic such as etymology.

Comment: Could you edit your question and ask how to prevent a tag from being reused in the future? Yesterday I went through retagging ten questions that were tagged `words` and today, a new question popped up using that very same tag.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Good idea; it is done.

Comment: There are several tags that invite off-topic questions: neologisms, lyrics, legalese, French etc ....

Answer (score 2):

I am deleting instances of [essay](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/essay). I will do a few each day, so they don't flood the new or newly edited question view.  Feel free to remove some if you're so inclined.

Comment: +1. We appreciate your work.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction You are most welcome! I am moving along, pruning a little each day. I think there are about 10 remaining.

Comment: There is a problem though. Until the tag is deleted any user can tag their question *essay* and the system will accept it. Hence my question to the mods: Is there a way to block  users from using this tag?

Comment: @Mari-LouA You're right, and that is happening already. New questions are appearing, using the same old essay tag. It would be great if users could be blocked from using it as a tag for future questions.

Comment: Well, there aren't any questions tagged with [esaay] right now, but jsyk there's a [tag-blocklisting feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295148/what-is-a-blocked-tag).

Comment: Thank you, @Heartspring for mentioning the tag blocking feature that has been developed! I see that the essay tag no longer exists at all!